# Ninject + Ninject Child Kernels + Continuous Azure WebJobs

Tags: azure, ninject, azure-webjobs, ninject-2, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have an **Azure WebJob** containing few different functions.

These functions need to be injected with some services by **Ninject** (using constructor injection). Since the standard JobActivator - the class which is responsible to instantiate jobs' classes - creates them by invoking a parameterless costructor, I cannot use that.

In order to do this, I've created a class implementing the `IJobActivator` interface - provided by the WebJobs SDK, following something similar to [this walkthrough](https://riptutorial.com/azure-webjobs/example/16701/dependency-injection-using-ninject).

Since I need this injected services to be alive until the function completes (and it seems that there is no way for the container to know when a function completes), I followed this workaround: https://blog.tech-fellow.net/2017/04/12/disposable-dependency-for-azure-webjob/

That article refers to a different container (StructureMap), but the concept is the same:

- inside the `JobActivator` a nested container is created
- that nested container is passed to the class that contains the function
- the class that contains the function implements `IDisposable` interface
- inside the `Dispose()` method that child container is disposed

Ninject, as far as I know, doesn't support nested containers, even if I found [this extension](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel) that seems to do something similar.

So what I would do is:

1. create a main kernel inside the WebJob, which I pass to the `JobActivator`
2. inside the `CreateInstance` of the `JobActivator`, I create a new Child Kernel, from the original one
3. I set that child kernel into the job's class instance
4. inside the `Dispose`method, I will dispose the child kernel

Questions:

- what do you think about this approach of creating child kernels? Is something that you would avoid?
- by checking the source code of the Child Kernel extension, it seems to me that, there is no particular change on the `Dispose` method of the child kernel. Am I correct if I say that by calling `Dispose()` on the child kernel, wont' dispose the main one?
- can you please confirm that as soon as a Ninject kernel il disposed (by calling its `Dispose()` method), then all the created instances - **even those that are InTransientScope** - will be disposed?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that creating a `ChildKernel` inside the `JobActivator` `Activate()` function is a very slow process.

My analysis shows that, if the concurrency on the `JobActivator` is high, the process of spinning up a new ChildKernel and activate the job will take a considerable amount of time. In my case it was a magnitude of order greater that the real job execution time, so it was totally unceptable.

What I did is serialize the process of job creation inside the `JobActivator`, by scoping to a particular `ExecutionContext` (a class that I created) the services that I needed to be scoped to a particular function execution.

All of my jobs implements the `IDisposable` interface. In the corresponding `Dispose()` method, I will dispose that particular `ExecutionContext`, letting Ninject Kernel (the only one instantiated inside the Program.cs) finally release services scoped to that object.